# propel:database:create access denied for user 'user'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, propel

For my Symfony2 project, I'm using Propel with MySQL.

When I deployed it on a server and ran:

```
php app/console propel:database:create --env=prod
```

I got this error:

```
[Propel] Exception caught

Unable to open PDO connection [wrapped: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)]
```

Which is really weird because when I run MySQL CLI with exactly the same host, user and password it works fine.

```
$ mysql -h localhost -u user -p
```

Propel-bundle: 1.2.13

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these steps

1. **Configure `config/databases.yml`** with the working username and password. Ensure you are using the correct password and port here

> ```
> propel:
>     class: sfPropelDatabase
>     param:
>       classname: PropelPDO
>       dsn: 'mysql:dbname=your-database-name;host=localhost'
>       port :  3306
>       username:         user
>       password :        your-password
>       encoding:         utf8
>       persistent:       true
>       pooling:          true
> ```

2. **Disable SELnux:** If SELinux is enabled which can block the connection. Try to disable that, although not the optimal for those that like of security on their systems